# How to change moment locale language dynamically in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, momentjs, angular-moment

I am developing a project using `angular-momentjs` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-momentjs) in ionicframework v1.

How to make my time language using `angular-momentjs` can be change dynamically? For example I wish to change to `en-au <-> ms-my` or any languages. Currently I call the function

`moment.locale('ms-my')` but it does not work at all. How to use it in the right way?

My sample codes:

```
if(cur_lang == 2) // Let say this is Malay language
{
    moment.locale('ms-my');
}
var link = URL_STUDENT_API+URL_API_VERSION_2+"/language";

$http.post(link, data).then(function(response) {
    if(response.data.status==CMN_PROCESS_STATUS_SUCCESSFUL){
        $rootScope.dataLang = angular.copy(response.data);
    }else{

    }
});
```

Comment: According to the documentation, you are using it properly. Have you tested that your if statement is executing as true? I typically just log something to the console to verify the code was reached.

Comment: Maybe these information [here](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/issues/126) and [here](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/issues/89) can help you.